# Error installing facebook plugin to login in apache cordova Visual studio

Tags: facebook, apache, cordova, authentication

I'm trying to develop an apache cordova application using Visual studio tools for apache cordova and the facebook connect plugin. With this plugin i'm trying to implement login with facebook.

I installed the plugin from the option custom / plugins, introducing the git repository https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin

The plugin was successfully installed, the solution compiles correctly.

In the index.html I included the script after platform overrides script:

...

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/platformOverrides.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="facebookConnectPlugin.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/index.js"></script>
</body>
```

..

The first question is that the facebookConnectPlugin.js was not automatically included within the www root folder in the plugin installation, in this case I don't know how to the application find this script, installing camera.js plugin happened the same but i had not problems in the inclusion, it seem the browser found the js. Where must be located facebookConnectPlugin.js? Do we have to include using the plugins folder? ej:

When I debug the project and tried to launch login with the following instructions it doesn't work:

```
var fbLoginSuccess = function (userData) {
    alert("UserInfo: " + JSON.stringify(userData));
}

function initLogin() {

   facebookConnectPlugin.login(["public_profile"],
            fbLoginSuccess,
            function (error) { alert("" + error) }
   );
}
```

The message I found with Ripple -Nexus (galaxy) emulator is:

"I Haz cheeseburger!

FacebookConnectPlugin.login

We seem to be missing some stuff :(

What is kinda cool though you can fill in the textarea to pass a json object to the callback you want to execute"

Summary:

Which is the src to include the facebookConnectPlugin.js?
Why I found an error with the emulator?

Best regards.